# Scroll View not working?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i am having some issue with my scroll view. My layout has two Images views one at the top and one at the bottom and i want my scroll view in the middle. The issue i am facing is the bottom image is shrinking to fit in the elements as the scroll view is not working. My code is as below.Thanks in advance

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/core"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cd_corelbg" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewhead"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cd_corehead" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewheading1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewhead"
        android:contentDescription="heading1"
        android:src="@drawable/cd_corheading1" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewheading1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewhead"
        android:contentDescription="heading1"
        android:src="@drawable/cd_coreback2"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewheading1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewhead"
        android:contentDescription="heading1"
        android:src="@drawable/cd_coredlheading1" />

      <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewheading1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewhead"
        android:contentDescription="heading1"
        android:src="@drawable/cd_coreback2"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>    

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewbase"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cd_cor" />
   </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you give a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi make your main layout as relative layout.  And also give condition to scroll view such that align below top image and and align above bottom image also for bottom image set align parrent bottom.